# Thunderbolt, Mini Display Port and HDMI

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport, thunderbolt-display

I got MDP-HDMI connector that does not work with iMac Mid 2011 with thunderbolt. I do not understand if it should (not) work or it is damaged.

Here is [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82071/67164) 
 that link [article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20043524-263.html)  that tells that iMac with thunderbolt should work with Mini Display Port devices.

Here is another [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23033/what-is-the-difference-between-thunderbolt-and-displayport-imacs-when-used-as-mo)  that tells that thunderbolt port requires thunderbolt **cable** they do not say it will not work with mini display port device. I understand that cable is not device.

It does not make situation more clear. If my MDP-HDMI convertor is damaged or not and I should by another version of connector or my iMac has some problem or I should turn something on to make connector working.

MDP-HDMI convertor has not separate cable. It just plugs in.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbolt ports allow connectivity to Mini DisplayPort. Since your converter just plugs in and then an HDMI cable (of any length that you supply) is then plugged into your converter and into a display, it should work just fine provided there is no damage to either the HDMI cable or the converter itself. If the Mac isn't recognizing the display, check the HDMI cable or the display first. Try to test the converter on another Mac with Thunderbolt before you deem it dead **but Thunderbolt does indeed work with Mini DisplayPort.**

Comment: Thank You. Very helpful. When I connect my phone to that cable it works. I tried display and TV to connect to my iMac. They do not work.

Comment: But the adapter is only used when testing with your iMac, correct? So that would suggest that the HDMI cable and display work fine and it's the Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter you're using on your iMac that's not working properly